# how to get onunload event on IE 

Tags: jquery

Hi i need to catch an onUnload event but its working in firefox not in IE . Can we capture onUnload event in IE?

Answer (score 2):

There is two events in IE you can use. Click the event-name to see the MSDN details.

- [onunload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536973(VS.85).aspx)
- [onbeforeunload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Could be that an installed plugin is disabling any unload handlers (see [this blog post](http://michaelteper.com/archive/2004/04/29/165.aspx)).  If that's the case you could remove the plugin or switch to use onbeforeunload.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the onbeforeunload event.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

       function unloadPage(){
           return "dont leave me this way";
       }

       window.onbeforeunload = unloadPage;

</script>
```